# Prevent/deny login to user based on extension attribute

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom attribute which I'd like to use while authenticating. For example, I have another status extension attribute which can have possible values like expired/blocked/inactive/active. While creating the user I will ensure there is a value populated for this.

At the time of login I'd like to consider this extension attribute as well. It may be possible that the user is entering the right password, but just because his extension attribute status has a value of expired/blocked/inactive I'd like to deny login and give a custom localized error message.

*Note*: I'm using custom policies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build claims transformations to determine whether the user account is activated and, if not, display an error message.

Firstly, you must declare a claim type that represents whether the user account is activated:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="accountActivated">
  <DisplayName>Account Activated</DisplayName>
  <DataType>boolean</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

Next, you must declare [a **CompareClaimToValue** claims transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#compareclaimtovalue) to determine whether the custom attribute is set to "Active":

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CheckAccountActivated" TransformationMethod="CompareClaimToValue">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AccountStatus" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="compareTo" DataType="string" Value="Active" />
    <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="equal" />
    <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountActivated" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Next, you must declare [an **AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue** claims transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#assertbooleanclaimisequaltovalue) to ensure that the user account is activated:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="EnsureAccountActivated" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountActivated" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
  </InputParameters>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Next, you must invoke the **EnsureAccountActivated** claims transformations from a copy of the **AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId** technical profile test that the user account is activated:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-EnsureAccountActivated">
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CheckAccountActivated" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="EnsureAccountActivated" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Lastly, you must invoke the **AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-EnsureAccountActivated** technical profile from a copy of the **SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email** technical profile to show the error message:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email-EnsureAccountActivated">
  ...
  <Metadata>
    ...
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Whoops, your e-mail address hasn't been verified, contact Support.</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-EnsureAccountActivated" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>
```

**UPDATE: 3 April 2019**

> This worked absolutely fine however need some help regarding localizing the custom error message.

You can customize the error message using [localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization).

The first step is to [enable localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization#set-up-the-explicit-list-of-supported-languages) for English and any other languages to be supported:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  ...
  <ContentDefinitions />
  <Localization>
    <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en">
      <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
      <SupportedLanguage>es</SupportedLanguage>
    </SupportedLanguages>
  </Localization>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

The second step is to define [the localized strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids) for each supported language for the page definition that is associated with the **SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email-EnsureAccountActivated** technical profile:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  ...
  <Localization>
    <SupportedLanguages />
    <LocalizedResources Id="api.signuporsignin.en">
      <LocalizedStrings>
         <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Whoops, your e-mail address hasn't been verified, contact Support.</LocalizedString>
      </LocalizedStrings>
    </LocalizedResources>
    <LocalizedResources Id="api.signuporsignin.es">
      <LocalizedStrings>
         <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Vaya, su dirección de correo electrónico no ha sido verificada, contacte a Soporte.</LocalizedString>
      </LocalizedStrings>
    </LocalizedResources>
  </Localization>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

(I don't speak Spanish so apologies if this is the incorrect translation.)

The last step is to [declare references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization#edit-the-contentdefinition-for-the-page) from the page definition to the localized resources:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  ...
  <ContentDefinitions>
    <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
      ...
      <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
         <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.en" />
         <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.es" />
      </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
    </ContentDefinition>
  </ContentDefinitions>
  <Localization />
</BuildingBlocks>
```

Comment: @Rupesh: Did this help?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I am going to try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Chris - This worked absolutely fine however need some help regarding localizing the custom error message. Any pointer as how to do that?

Comment: Hi @RupeshKumarprasad I've updated the above answer with information about localization.

Comment: Thanks Chris - please help me with another thing what if i want to show different error message based on extension attribute value. suppose extension_AccountStatus attribute can have three possible value active/expired/blocked. I want to show different error message based on extension_AccountStatus, if value is active then allow to login and issue the token where as if extension_AccountStatus is blocked then show a different localized error message "your account is blocked", in case if value is expired then show the localized error message "your account is expired". Thanks in advance!